# jQuery: Adding a mouseenter event to a custom click function

Tags: jquery, click, mouseevent, swipe

I've been experimenting with 'mouseenter' event to an additional mouse hove function over an existing click function, and doesn't seem to find the correct formula to achieve the intended effect.

Original code:

```
    $('.navhandle, .navcontainer, #tray-button, .page-template-template-home-php .lines, .single-portfolio .lines').hover(
function(){ $('#supersized img').addClass('resize'); //add class for css3 transitions
$thisid = $(this).attr("id");
$thisclass = $(this).attr("class");
$navnow = $('.navhandle').css('left');

if ($navnow == navhandleinit) {

if (($thisid == 'tray-button')) {
    $('#thumb-tray').stop().animate({bottom : 0}, 300);
}
    $('#prevslide').stop().animate({left: 25 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navcontainer').stop().animate({ left: -210 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navhandle').stop().animate({ left: -10 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
     $('.mainbody').stop().animate({marginLeft: 10}, 500, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ $('#supersized img').removeClass('resize'); }); //remove css3 transition class after completion
    $('.videowrapper').animate({width: '120%', paddingLeft:0}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');


    $('.nav').fadeOut(500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.navhandle').toggleClass("rightarrow");
},function(){ $('#prevslide').stop().animate({left: 245}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navcontainer').stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navhandle').stop().animate({ left: navhandleinit}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.mainbody').stop().animate({marginLeft: 220}, 500, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ $('#supersized img').removeClass('resize'); }); //remove css3 transition class after completion
    $('#thumb-tray').stop().animate({bottom : -$('#thumb-tray').height()}, 300);
    $('.videowrapper').animate({paddingLeft: 220, width: '100%'}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.nav').fadeIn(500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.navhandle').toggleClass("rightarrow");

    $navnow = navhandleinit;
    }
```

Simply changing 'click' to 'mouseenter' works on triggering the effect, but not isolating it to specific elements.

The failed attempt:

```
  jQuery(function($) {

var navhandleinit = $('.navhandle').css('left');
var navwidth = $('.navcontainer').width() + 30;
var mainmargin = $('.mainbody').css('margin-left');
var $navnow = $('.navhandle').css('left');
var navtray = $('#thumb-tray').css('left');

$('.navhandle, .navcontainer').mouseenter(function() {

$('#supersized img').addClass('resize');
$thisid = $(this).attr("id");
$thisclass = $(this).attr("class");
$navnow = $('.navhandle').css('left');

if ($navnow == navhandleinit) {

if (($thisid == 'tray-button')) {
    $('#thumb-tray').stop().animate({bottom : 0}, 300);
}
    $('#prevslide').stop().animate({left: 25 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navcontainer').stop().animate({ left: -210 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navhandle').stop().animate({ left: -10 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
     $('.mainbody').stop().animate({marginLeft: 10}, 500, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ $('#supersized img').removeClass('resize'); }); //remove css3 transition class after completion
    $('.videowrapper').animate({width: '120%', paddingLeft:0}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');


    $('.nav').fadeOut(500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.navhandle').toggleClass("rightarrow");



} else {

    $('#prevslide').stop().animate({left: 245}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navcontainer').stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.navhandle').stop().animate({ left: navhandleinit}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    $('.mainbody').stop().animate({marginLeft: 220}, 500, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ $('#supersized img').removeClass('resize'); }); //remove css3 transition class after completion
    $('#thumb-tray').stop().animate({bottom : -$('#thumb-tray').height()}, 300);
    $('.videowrapper').animate({paddingLeft: 220, width: '100%'}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.nav').fadeIn(500, 'easeOutCubic');

    $('.navhandle').toggleClass("rightarrow");

    $navnow = navhandleinit;
}

});
```

});

How can I effectively add a mouseenter event, and optionally, a swipe event for tablets, while maintaining the original click event function?

Live page available at http://stage.daylight.pro.

I'd appreciate your help, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was just omitted from your code here, but neither of your examples close the `hover()` and `mouseenter()` methods.
Your failed attempt *should* end with a ); like

```
$('.navhandle, .navcontainer').mouseenter(function() { ... });
```

Aside from that, I'm not sure why your `hover()` or `mouseenter()` methods would affect any click methods defined (unless something in the `click()` function specifically overrides something in your `hover()` function).

UPDATE:
If I'm understanding you, you have the following parameters/goals:

1. Existing code within a jQuery `hover` function
2. You'd like to keep that intact, but add an additional `mouseenter` function
3. There's also an existing `click` function that you'd like to maintain as well
4. Also, you want touch users to experience `hover` and `click` functions instead of just `click` only (since touch users experience `hover` and `click` at the same instant)

As far as the `mouseenter` vs. `hover`. I would make it a little cleaner for yourself (and other developers) and separate out the functions.  Rather than defining anonymous functions within the `hover` parameters, say something like:

```
$('myDiv').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
function hoverIn() { ... }
function hoverOut() { ... }
```

This way you can more easily see your over and out code distinctly.  Also, this is better for reuse if you want another function to, say, disable it's call.

Your `hover`, `mouseenter`, and `mouseout` function should not get in the way of `click` events.  With each interaction, you will have both `mouseenter` and `click` happen in succession.

Maybe use jQuery mobile for `tap` event that will suspend the click momentarily.  Ultimately, though, the `hover` event is only a nicety and it would most likely annoy people on touch devices to have to wait momentarily while your hover event fires before firing the click event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I only wrote the part that I modified, and I have updated the code. As you can see, click event were no longer there and I simply have no idea how can I combine hover/uiswipe, on top of the existing click, instead of replacing it.

Comment: Are you specifically wondering about using hover and click so that touch users will still be able to see both events triggered?

Comment: Yes, and I also want desktop users to also able to trigger the functions with mouseover, in addition to click. Any tips?

Comment: Except #1, all is true. Existing code is within a custom jQuery script that has a click only function.